# Document schema version, 2.2, is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am struggling to get EC2 instances deployed via an ASG joined to the domain.

I get the following error each time

`New-SSMAssociation : Document schema version, 2.2, is not supported by association that is created with instance id`

I have tried various schema versions detailed [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/document-schemas-features.html) however all fail with the same error

**SSMdoc.tf**

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "ad-join-domain" {
  name          = "ad-join-domain"
  document_type = "Command"
  content = jsonencode(
    {
      "schemaVersion" = "2.2"
      "description"   = "aws:domainJoin"
      "parameters" : {
        "directoryId" : {
          "description" : "(Required) The ID of the directory.",
          "type" : "String"
        },
        "directoryName" : {
          "description" : "(Required) The name of the domain.",
          "type" : "String"
        },
        "dnsIpAddresses" : {
          "description" : "(Required) The IP addresses of the DNS servers for your directory.",
          "type" : "StringList"
        },
      },
      "mainSteps" = [
        {
          "action" = "aws:domainJoin",
          "name"   = "domainJoin",
          "inputs" = {
            "directoryId" : data.aws_directory_service_directory.adgems.id,
            "directoryName" : data.aws_directory_service_directory.adgems.name,
            "dnsIpAddresses" : [data.aws_directory_service_directory.adgems.dns_ip_addresses]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}
```

**template.tf**

```
data "template_file" "ad-join-template" {
  template = <<EOF
  <powershell>
    Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region eu-west-2
    Set-Variable -name instance_id -value (Invoke-Restmethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
    New-SSMAssociation -InstanceId $instance_id -Name "${aws_ssm_document.ad-join-domain.name}"
  </powershell>
  EOF
}
```

The above is then called from the aws_launch_template terraform resource.

Comment: out of curiosity have you verified that your variable(s) are set properly, such as instance_id? Can you echo it in your launch template bootstrap after setting it?

Comment: Hi yes on the instance I have run the script manually and all variables are valid.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the issue using a different format of the `New-SSMAssociation` command as found in the examples in the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-SSMAssociation.html

This is the example listed with small modifications

```
$target = @{Key="instanceids";Values=@("i-0cb2b964d3e14fd9f")}
New-SSMAssociation -Name 'ad-join-domain' -Target $target
```

Please note that the values portion should be changed to hold the actual instance ID that is in used.

Comment: Apparently we can now rename the computer and join the domain at the same time by specifying the `hostname` parameter.
https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/commit/7c57ffb91eb244bb8e6873fb414b5c823c793c87

Comment: To ensure the computer name is unique I strip the `i-` prefix off the instance id then convert it from Base 16 (hexadecimal) to Base36 to make it fit within the 15 characters allowed. Apparently NetBios computer names are not allowed to be comprised of digits only so this strategy may not work 100% of the time.